# jS centering function not working for one element on page load, just resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Edit: I know this isn't the best approach and it can be done with css but I'm simply wondering why the code doesn't work for the one element like it does for the other 2. I want to understand that.

In my jS I have the following to center divs in a page, but it's only triggering for smIcons when I resize, not on page load as well. It works on page load for comingSoon and logo, just not smIcons. Why is this?

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    centerInViewport('#comingSoon');
    centerInViewport('#logo');
    centerInViewport('#smIcons');

    $(window).resize(function () {
        centerInViewport('#comingSoon');
        centerInViewport('#smIcons');
        centerInViewport('#logo');
    });


});

function centerInViewport(e) {

    $docWidth = $(document).width();
    $docHeight = $(document).height();
    $elWidth = $(e).width();
    $elHeight = $(e).height();
    $offsetW = ($docWidth - $elWidth) / 2;
    $offsetH = ($docHeight - $elHeight) / 2;

    $(e).css("marginLeft", $offsetW + "px");

    if(e == '#comingSoon'){
        $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH+200 + "px");    
    }else if(e == '#smIcons'){
        $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH+50 + "px");    
    }else if(e == '#logo'){
        $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH-150 + "px");    
    }
}
```

css:

```
#comingSoon {
  position: absolute;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
}

#smIcons {
  position: absolute;
}
```

How it loads:

[image]

How it looks when resized (how it should look when loaded):

[image]

Comment: do you mind me asking why you would do that with js and not CSS?

Comment: @Dominik trying to practice jS, and also because I don't know how to get the size of browser window in cs

Comment: fair enough if this is just a proof of concept and a learning thingy :) all in all using js to do layout stuff is considered bad practise if intended for production.

Comment: try call the calculation function in $(window).load() perhaps? i think it's because the element is not loaded yet so the width calculation return 0

Comment: @bondythegreat yep that was it, thank you! can you leave that as an answer so I can accept it and give you credit? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try call the calculation function in `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()` since the calculation of element's width is done when all the elements are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning places elements absolutely on the screen. Change it to relative? To adapt to screen resizing?

Also this code

```
 if (e == '#comingSoon') {
     $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH + 200 + "px");
 } else if (e == '#smIcons') {
     $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH + 50 + "px");
 } else if (e == '#logo') {
     $(e).css("marginTop", $offsetH - 150 + "px");
 }
```

Executes for all screen sizes. It's fixed. The number of pixels get reduced substantially when resized. So it gets pushed further away on smaller screens than on larger.

Comment: yep I see the issue with hard coding those pixels, just doing it for now to demo. 

as for changing to relative, it made everything disappear from the screen...

Answer (score 0):

You could use css for centering elements

```
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
```

Comment: I was having some issues with different browser sizings